# Is it possible to point http link(it gives an image) to the UIimageview in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, https, uiimageview

I was trying to put the htttp link to the UIimageView but it doesn't show up me an image. But when i point a local file in the local storage, it shows me the image. Please help me guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do something like this

```
__block UIImage *img;
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"some_link_to_image"];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    img = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        yourImageView.image = img;
    });
});
```

Comment: It's not working. It doesn't show me anything. I already did this thing when i was trying to parse the JSON information.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download it before displaying. You have different alternatives, you could use a Cocoa API or just an external library to manage the request.

One of the external libraries to handle HTTP requests is [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
In particular it offers a very convenient category `UIImageView+AFNetworking.h` You can use it like this:

```
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
//...
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://here_your_url_to_the_image"];
[yourImageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

Comment: Thank You. Basically, the link gives me JSON information from fbgraph. I think authentication thing is not needed because when i type the same link in browser it gives me the image. From JSON information I pointed to one object which gives me an image. I took that object and pointed to UIImageView.

Comment: nice!, Do not forget to upvote and choose the accepted answer ;)